# Oracle APEX tree expand to child

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

I'm working with Oracle APEX 20.1 currently and I'm trying to create a function that expandle all way to specific child.

First I'm looking form specific nodes and adding class to it

```
$( "#tree_tree" ).treeView( "find", {
    depth: -1,
    findAll: true,
    match: function(n) {
        return n.label.indexOf( "Text" ) >= 0;
    }
} ).addClass("filterMatch");
```

Now there is a method to expand this nodes

```
$( "#tree_tree" ).treeView( "expand", $('.filterMatch') );
```

But it only expands the nodes with this class. It doesn't expands parents nodes.
So if there is 3 levels and node with this class is on 3lvl and the tree is fully collapsed, nothing happens.

How to expand all parents of specific nodes?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some months ago and came up with this:

```
function getParentArray(n){
    var arr = [], ln = n;
    while (ln._parent !== null) arr.push(ln = ln._parent);
    return arr.reverse(); // in correct order
};

function expandUpTo(aID) {
    if (aID == '') return;
    var tree = $("#mytree div[role='tree']");
    var treenode = tree.treeView("find", {
        depth: -1,
        findAll: true,
        match: function(n) {
            return parseInt(n.id.split(':')[0]) == aID;
        }
    });

    var mnode = tree.treeView("getNodes",treenode);
    
    if (mnode[0]) {

        getParentArray(mnode[0]).forEach(function(p){
            //get the DOM element for the datanode
            var ex = tree.treeView("getTreeNode",p);
            //expand each node along the path
            tree.treeView("expand",ex);
        });
    }
}
```

While its pretty easy to find a certain node, you need to traverse the nodes in the correct order. That's why the function `getParentArray` includes a `reverse`.
Note that my `IDs` were containing some colon delimited data, which is why I am using split to get the first element. If you don't need this, that line can be eased up to this:

```
return n.id == aID;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create on Page load Dynamic actions with True action as Expand Tree, which is readily available in `Action -> Component -> Expand Tree.`

It expands the tree to its leaf level at all the levels.